# Updating a textview in different layout xml from the main activity

Tags: android

I've created a new .xml file in my layout folder called `log.xml`. It only contains one `TextView`.

Is it possible to set the text on the textview located in the log.xml from my main activity? Or can it only be set when in an activity which uses the log.xml as view? Hope you get what i mean here, otherwise ill elaborate.

Thanks

Comment: your mainActivity has a main layout which is called main.xml , and you have added a new layout log.xml , soo you should create a new Activity , and you can change of course its value , from the first Activity ( MainActivity ) by using intents

Comment: When do you plan on displaying log.xml; in a new Activity, as a row in a ListView (or Spinner, etc), as a new view in your current Activity?

Comment: @Sam As a new activity when clicking on a button in my main.xml.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you don't set the xml you are talking about on "setContentView()" you can always get it with layout inflater. You'll have to add the tv to the current layout using addView() though.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.log, null); //log.xml is your file.
TextView tv = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.tv); //get a reference to the textview on the log.xml file.
```

Comment: Hi Nuno, The above inflating is working fine. I want to update textview value in particular position. any help.? Because,inside layout, i hvae button, when click button, its get response from server and show the update in particular textview

Answer (score 0):

Unless log.xml is included in the current, visible layout findViewById() will return null.

Since you want to set the TextView's text when you load it in a new activity, you can pass the new String in the Intent used to start your Activity.

In the appropriate onClick() from your First Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Second.class);
intent.putExtra("myTextViewString", textString);
startActivity(intent);
```

In your Second Activity's onCreate():

```
setContentView(R.layout.log);

TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras != null) {
    String newText = extras.getString("myTextViewString");
    if(newText != null) {
        textView.setText(newText);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below solution worked for me -

1. Get View object of layout XML file (ex. toast_loading_data) -

   ```
   View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_loading_data,
           (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));
   ```
2. Get the TextView element from this View (ex. TextView id - toast_text)-

   ```
   TextView tvToast = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toast_text);
   ```
3. Set text of the TextView -

   ```
   tvToast.setText("Loading data for " + strDate + " ...");
   ```
4. Below is snippet for customized Toast message from Main Activity -

   ```
   View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_loading_data,
           (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));
   TextView tvToast = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toast_text);
   tvToast.setText("Loading data for " + strDate + " ...");
   Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
   toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0); //Set toast gravity to bottom
   toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);   //Set toast duration
   toast.setView(layout);  //Set the custom layout to Toast
   ```

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

I think I understand what you are trying to say. If you do this:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);    
tv.setText(output);
```

where `textView2` is the id of the text view that you want to set the text of, you can set it to any string value using the `setText()` function. Hope this helps!

Comment: If log.xml is not currently displayed, `tv` will be null.

Comment: Could he do this?
`TextViewActivity.findViewById(R.id.textView)`
where `TextViewActivity` is the activity with the text view?

Comment: I don't believe so, findViewById() only works on the current Activity or an inflated View.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.

findViewById() does not work if the 'id' you are looking for is in a different activity.

Please refer to @nuno-gonçalves answer which is correct.