# Android Adding view from inflate layout and how to update particular textview value in layout

Tags: android, listview, view, layout-inflater, android-viewgroup

I have created view from inflating separate layout. I used for loop to create view more than 5 view like an ListView. Here I want call balance check. Inside view, I will click balance button and once receive response from server, I want to update particular TextView in an existing created view. Any help? I am expecting same for phonepe app balance checking page. [image] while scrolling also, it should not hide the updated balance.          My Ref stack link: 
[Updating a textview in different layout xml from the main activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173850/updating-a-textview-in-different-layout-xml-from-the-main-activity)

[Create a custom View by inflating a layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328838/create-a-custom-view-by-inflating-a-layout)
My Sample Code:

```
for (int i=0; i<AccNoList.size; i++) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_table_row, myTable, true);
    inflater.setId(i);
    ImageButton balancebtn = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.balancebtn);
    TextView    textview_accnumber   = (TextView)    v.findViewById(R.id.textview_accnumber);
    textview_accnumber.setText("Text for this row");
    balancebtn.setId(i); // So that when it is clicked we know which one has been clicked!
    balancebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    // once received value from server, i want to update the same row textview balance.
    checkBalance(i);
    }
    });          
    textview_accnumber.setId(i);
    tr.setId(i);
    textview_accnumber.setText(AccNoList.get(i));

    linearlayout.addView(inflater);
}
```

Comment: **i used for loop to create view more than 5 view like an listview** -> do you have done using list of views? 
(like    View[] array or ArrayList<View> )

Comment: pls check my above sample code

Comment: what is `position` here?

Comment: position is for i only. i have another original project is there. here, simple textview update inside layout means, i will do it. here, am communicating server, its taking more code to receive response, anyway, am come out of the inside layout.

Comment: `linearlayout.addView(inflater);` -> How did you add inflater ? did this work? .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update a view property you have to store that view reference. 
In your case store the views you have created from inflating separate layout.

```
View view1 = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layoutId, parent, false);
View view2 = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layoutId, parent, false);
View view3 = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(layoutId, parent, false);
```

Then when you receive response from server, get reference the child view you want to update by `findViewById()` method and  update child's property.

**Example:**

```
TextView textView1 = view1.findViewById(viewId);
textView1.setText("Updated Text");

TextView textView2 = view2.findViewById(viewId);
textView2.setText("Updated Text");
```

**Edit**

```
// declare it as global
View views[] = new View[size]

for (int i=0; i<AccNoList.size; i++) {
  LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  views[i] =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_table_row, myTable, true);
   //inflater.setId(i);
  ImageButton balancebtn = (ImageButton) views[i].findViewById(R.id.balancebtn);
  TextView    textview_accnumber   = (TextView)    views[i].findViewById(R.id.textview_accnumber);
  textview_accnumber.setText("Text for this row");
   // balancebtn.setId(i); // So that when it is clicked we know which one has been clicked!
  balancebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
     // once received value from server, i want to update the same row textview balance.
       checkBalance(i);
    }
  });          
  //textview_accnumber.setId(i);
  //tr.setId(i);
  textview_accnumber.setText(AccNoList.get(i));

  linearlayout.addView(inflater);
}
```

**checkBalance** method

```
public void checkBalance(final int position){
  // .................
  // ..............
 // after received response
    updateStatus(position);
}
```

**updateStatus** method

```
private void updateStatus(int position, String text){
  if(position < views.length){
     TextView textview_accnumber = (TextView)views[i].findViewById(R.id.textview_accnumber);
     if(textview_accnumber != null)
       textview_accnumber.setText(text);
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for update yousuf. am using for loop for inflating layout and add view. dont know, how to global access with specific row view. here, i dont have any view array to retrieve it.

Comment: Best way to solve this problem is to use `ListView` and `Adapter`. Android provides `ListView` and `Adapter` for this type of problem. When new data source is available you just have to notify the adapter thats it, `ListView` and `Adapter` will handle all for you. Try using `ListView` and `Adapter`.

Comment: than you yousuf. let me check above it. also, i will try for listview also.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **array of views** to identify them easily.

```
View[] viewlist=new View[AccNoList.size];
    for (int i=0; i<AccNoList.size; i++) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        viewlist[i]=  inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_table_row, myTable, true);
        inflater.setId(position);
        ...
        balancebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        // once received value from server, i want to update the same row textview balance.

        checkBalance(position);
        ((TextView)viewlist[i].findViewById(that_id)).setText("Your Text");
        }
        });          
       ...
    }
```

Comment: thank for reply. i am trying for same. but, i did not get my textview data update. but, i did not receive any error.  ((TextView)inflated_layout_view[0].findViewById(R.id.textview_resp)).setText("Your Text");